# Como ancorar um redirect no APS.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, mvc

Como posso mandar o usuário para certo bloco da página passando o id na url. Por exemplo: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type, como passar esse type no ASP.NET MVC utilizando o `return RedirectToAction`.

A linha do meu código está assim: `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`,
tentei `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home",new{#type});` mas ele não aceita o "#".

E outra pergunta, qual o nome desse recurso onde você passa o "#" na url da página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este recurso se chama Ancora, para realizar em um redirect no MVC, ao invés do **RedirectToAction**, segue a linha de código correta:

```
return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home")+"#type");
```

Comment: Junio , não funcionou, está retornando essa pagina: https://prnt.sc/fmupc6

Comment: Junior eu arrumei a linha que você me passou, deu certo ! o que estava dando problema era a "/" do "/#type";

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti, realmente havia me esquecido da "/" vou editar a pergunta, vlw.

Comment: na verdade eu tinha editado, o correto é sem barra :D

Answer (score 0):

Basta usar HTML mesmo, faça assim:

O link:

```
<a href="#idDoElemento">Meu link teste</a>
```

Seu elemento

```
<p id="idDoElemento">teste</p>
```

ou seja, no link, escreva # + o id do elemento que você quer que o link aponte.

Se chama âncora

Comment: O elemento no HTML se chama "âncora" (originalmente tinha que usar uma _tag_ `<a name="abc">`, a parte da URL que começa com `#` chama-se "fragmento".

Answer (score 0):

Esse recurso se chama âncora no HTML.
Você precisa criar a âncora e depois é só chamar ela em qualquer link.

Criando a âncora:

```
<a name="NOME_DA_ANCORA"></a>
```

Indo para a âncora:

```
<a href="#NOME_DA_ANCORA">Ir para topo!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sei que é uma pergunta já antiga e que recebeu algumas soluções, mas há uma outra alternativa mais específica dentro do AspNet, que é um dos overloads do método ActionLink conforme documentação [aqui](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

Neste overload passamos o id do elemento html que servirá de âncora como **fragment** que será incluído na URL com #.

Segue um exemplo utilizando um **Redirect** dentro de um **Controller**:

```
return Redirect(Url.ActionLink(action: nameof(HomeController.Index), controller: nameof(Home), protocol: null, fragment: "type", values: null));
```

Alí é possível ainda passar um objeto com valores de roteamento no parâmetro **values** (exemplo: `new { Area = "Admin", id = model.Id }`, etc. Gerando uma url com o roteamento adequado:

```
http://localhost:5000/{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}#{fragment}
```

É possível também na View criar botões com este direcionamento para âncoras:

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText: "Return", action: nameof(HomeController.Index), controller: nameof(Home), protocol: null, hostname: null, fragment: "type", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

Obs. Deixei acima o nome dos parâmetros para fins didáticos mas eles podem ser omitidos sem problemas nas chamadas.